# createsuperuser django jython freeze in password

Tags: python, django, web, jython

When entering the admin super user, I'm able to enter the user name and email address, but the prompt just hangs on the password (pressing  does not work). This also happens when using the "createsuperuser" option. So the super user cannot be set.

Comment: What version of Django you are using?

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30250032/django-createsuperuser-cannot-enter-password

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django createsuperuser cannot enter password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30250032/django-createsuperuser-cannot-enter-password)

Answer (score -1):

[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPXiy.jpg)

The password will not be shown in terminal when you type. You can type a password then press enter and retype it again and press enter.

It should work.

Also make sure your password is minimum 8 character long, with a numerical value.

Comment: Yes. New uses may get confuses, in terminal, password doesn't show up as you type. But it's there. You should use same password twice to verify that password.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577)