# Django createsuperuser cannot enter password

Tags: python, django, superuser

I am learning django, and I have a mysite folder. When I synced the database it prompted me to create a superuser. I typed yes, and got halfway through the forms but I couldn't enter any characters when it wanted a password. I searched google and found:
    python manage.py createsuperuser
The same thing happened, I could not enter a password. I am using django 1.5 and python 2.7 in case you need to know.

Comment: What do you mean you could not enter a password? Any error message that appears?

Comment: Are you talking about the password prompt not showing any characters when you type? That's normal. It's simply hiding whatever you're typing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The password or *** characters will not be shown as you type them.

Just type your intended password and press enter. This will give prompt for password confirmation.

```
Password (again):
```

If you get any error messages post here.

Answer (score 0):

The password is usually hidden in your IDE so it is not showing up when you're typing it out.
Just type the password press enter and re-enter the same thing.
Hope this solves the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: admin, admin_interface, auth, contenttypes, myapp, sessions
Running migrations:
Applying myapp.0002_alter_student_id...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).